# My JavaFX Tooltip isn't showing up on a chart data node

Tags: javafx

I'm playing around with JavaFX and wanted to add a tooltip that pops up with the data value when the mouse is hovering over the node. I found several links and answers out there describing CSS methods for doing it, or using `Tooltip.install(node, tooltip)` and while I could get a tooltip working on a dummy example, I was still having no luck with the chart, using code like so :

```
LineChart<Number, Number> chart = new LineChart(xaxis, yaxis);
ObservableList<Data<Number, Number>> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
Data<Number, Number> d1 = new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>(5, 15);
Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip("15");
Tooltip.install(d1.getNode(), tooltip);
data.add(d1);
Data<Number, Number> d2 = new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>(10, 25);
Tooltip tooltip2 = new Tooltip("25");
Tooltip.install(d2.getNode(), tooltip2);
data.add(d2);
chart.setData(data);

//add chart to scene etc etc etc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some digging, the issue here is that a data element (XYChart.Data) does not have a node created at construction time. `chart.setData(data)` will populate the node field - I believe this is to allow the user to create and set their own nodes if so desired. So `d1.getNode()` is actually returning null, and `Tooltip.install()` is silently failing.

Moving the `Tooltip.install` call *after* `chart.setData` solves the issue.